# Error en el formulario de login: Undefined array key "register_link"

Tags: wordpress, login

como estan?
Estoy temrinando un sistema de usuarios con WP
y me doy cuenta que el widget que uso para logearse arroga el error
**

> Warning: Undefined array key "register_link"

**
Me dice que el error esta en esta linea:

```
if ( 'custom' === $settings['register_link'] && ! empty( $settings['register_url']['url'] ) ) {
```

**Tienen idea que puede ser?**
Wordpress todo actualizado

Comment: Y si haces var_dump() de $settings['register_url'] y $settings['register_url']['url'] que te retorna? Ese widget, es un plugin o lo programaste, por favor lee [ask] y como hacer un [example]

Comment: Es un plugin complementrio de Elementor Free y trae ese widget de inicio de sesion que me viene genial. Pero me pone ese mensaje abajo del form de logeo.

Comment: Pero si te deja logearte o solo te da ese error?, el error da porque parece que [register_url] no existe, si te deja logear intenta desactivar el wp_debug o usar un isset() en la verificación de ese dato, no podemos ayudarte si no das mas información, una vez mas te invito a leer [ask]

Comment: hay varios plugins hechos sasinomás que no limpian los warnings, tendras que contactar al autor para que te oriente a que se debe que no exista el key, como dirty fix podes meterle un `if ( 'custom' === ($settings['register_link']??'lol') ...` así si no existe no pasa la condición